# Laravel — How to get string value from object via model method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have model House with relation hasMany HousePhotos.
I try get link to main photo from table house_photos.

```
class House extends Model
{

    public function photos(){

    return $this->hasMany('app\HousePhoto');

    }

    public function get_main_photo(){

    return $this->photos()->where('main', true);

    }

}
```

Controller:

```
$house=House::find(1);
```

In View i use

```
{{$house->main_photo()->link}}
```

and got error.

When i use

```
{{$house->main_photo()}}
```

i got object. How to get string value of link to photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to understand the difference between the Builder object and the Collection object.

As it is now, function `get_main_photo` returns a Builder object (actually a Relation object, which contains a Builder).

On these objects you can call function `get()` to finish the query and get the results. In this case you will get a Collection object, which you will be able to iterate.
Alternatively, in this case you seem to only have one 'main photo' per house, so instead you can call `first()`:

```
public function get_main_photo(){    
    return $this->photos()->where('main', true)->first();    
}
```

This will return the single associated model, on which you will be able to access `->link` (if the model was found).

---

Remember at any point while debugging you can call the convenient `dd` function (which dumps the object passed as parameter and terminates the applicacion) to see what type of object you are dealing with, and all its attributes.